# SCript does not generate a new workbook for each filtered value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, filtering

This script loops through each value within a filtered column with the aim of filtering one by one, copy the data, create a new workbook, paste it and save it.

It it now creating a signle new workbook with all the worksheets, instead of one workbook per worksheet.

Can someone point out how can I mend the code to create one workbook per value filtered?
On the other hand, the workbook is also keeping the original sheet1. I am also looking on how to remove it, but thought it would be importat to let you know.

````
Sub test()
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
' -------------------

Dim x As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim last As Long
Dim sht As String
Dim newBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim Workbk As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet



'Specify sheet name in which the data is stored
sht = "Report"

'Workbook where VBA code resides
Set Workbk = ThisWorkbook

'New Workbook
Set newBook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
Workbk.Activate

Set ws = Workbk.Worksheets(sht)

'change filter column in the following code
last = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "BR").End(xlUp).Row

With ws
Set rng = .Range("A1:BR" & last)
End With

ws.Range("G1:G" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("BT1"), Unique:=True
  
For Each x In ws.Range([BT2], Cells(Rows.Count, "BT").End(xlUp))

With rng
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=x.Value
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

newBook.Sheets.Add(After:=newBook.Sheets(newBook.Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
newBook.Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
End With
Next x

' Turn off filter
ws.AutoFilterMode = False

With Application
.CutCopyMode = False
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

' -------------------
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Check."
    
End Sub ```
````

Comment: Using variables doesn't slow down your code and makes it more readable. For example, if you do `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Workbk.Worksheets(sht)`, you can replace all occurrences of `Workbk.Sheets(sht)` with `ws` and correct the most critical line with `For Each x In ws.Range("BT2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "BT").End(xlUp)).Cells`.

Comment: Hey, VBasic, thanks for pointing this out! I already updated the script and does not stop at the mentioned line above. However, it still creates a new workbook where it pastes all of the worksheets generated. Do you know how I may change the code into one workbooks per worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `Workbooks.Add` line inside the loop.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub test()
  
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iLastRowBT As Long
    Dim folder As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    'Workbook where VBA code resides
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Report")
    folder = wb.Path & "\"

    With ws
        'change filter column in the following code
        iLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "BR").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("BT:BT").Clear
        .Range("G1:G" & iLastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Range("BT1"), Unique:=True
        Set rng = .Range("A1:BR" & iLastRow)
        iLastRowBT = .Cells(Rows.Count, "BT").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    ' create workbooks
    For Each cel In ws.Range("BT2:BT" & iLastRowBT)

        ' Open New Workbook
        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
        Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets(1)
        wsNew.Name = cel.Value

        ' filter and copy data
        With rng
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=cel.Value
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        End With

        ' paste and save
        wsNew.Paste
        wbNew.SaveAs folder & cel.Value & ".xlsx"
        wbNew.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next

    ' Turn off filter
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    MsgBox iLastRowBT - 1 & " Workbooks created in " & folder, vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi CDP, thank you very much for this. Specially for the line that takes the path directly from the workbook in which the script is stored.

Comment: Hi CDP, good day and happy new year! I was wondering if you had a version of this script that adds the recently created workbook to an email. In case not, would you suggest to create a different script for it and call if from this one?

Comment: Hi @Jorge How are you going to determine which person/email address the workbook is to be sent to ? Or is it one email with all workbooks attached ? I think I would fill a collection object inside the for loop and then pass that to a separate sub or function at the end.

Comment: Hi CDP, thanks for coming back. Since the script gets each unique value from column G I did an xlookup on the adjacent column to bring in the Emails. It will be the first time creating a collection for me. I will try my hardest but probably I will mess up haha. I would be thankful for your input on a separate post I might make.